# Create a node using node inside NODE-RED

Tags: node-red

I want to create a mqtt node subscibe with custom topic that (I set up from another node that has function to add that node)

Comment: You need to add a lot  more detail here. Do you mean a MQTT publish node or a MQTT subscribe node?

Comment: I want to create mqtt subscribe with topic that I attached from a node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MQTT-in nodes do not support dynamically settings the topic.

You have a few options

1. Set the topic in the MQTT-in node to a wildcard e.g. `#` and then use a switch node to filter incoming messages based on a comparing the topic of the incoming message to a context variable. If you have a high volume of messages this might cause performance problems
2. Set the topic with an environment variable. You can use the `${ENV_VAR_NAME}` to set configuration values at flow deployment time. This would mean knowing what topic you need before starting Node-RED
3. Use the Node-RED [Admin API](https://nodered.org/docs/api/admin/) to edit the current flow. While this is closest to the question you have asked, this is a very complex solution as it means crafting the correct payload to modify the currently running flow and then triggering a deploy.